# Can't access web service when connected to the network :: HTTP 407

Tags: c#, service, access-denied, windows-xp-sp3

I have a console application that communicates with a web service. Both of them are on the same machine.

When I am accessing the web service with the LAN disabled, it connects without a problem. But if the LAN is enabled and connected to our office network, I receive this error:

"HTTP 407 Proxy Authentication required - The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy service is denied."

We've been hunting the source of the problem for three days now. We have tried everything that we can think of. Any ideas what's causing the problem?

Additional notes:
- The machine is in a Workgroup setup but with DNS suffix (computer.local). When accessing the web service, we type the address as "http://machine.computer.local/service.asmx"

- I talked to the IT guys and they said that we don't have an ISA server installed
- There is no "proxy" set in IE.
- The machine is in mint condition.

Comment: I would start with some network debugging tools like Wireshark and Fiddler2.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. :) In your opinion, which is more user-friendly of the two?

Comment: Wireshark is less user-friendly, but better for lower level debugging.  I would try Wireshark only after being unable to solve it with Fiddler2.  NB Wireshark won't work on the loopback interface under Windows.

Comment: I used Wireshark and monitored my NIC card. It turns out that HTTP request are being transferred to a proxy server; even local HTTP request to the local IIS. Is that even normal?

Comment: Definitely not normal given what you said in your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the IT guys that I've talked with is not aware of the corporate-wide ISA server.

Using Wireshark, I dumped the data to an HTML file (a standard HTTP 407 error page). It clearly showed the Hostname and IP address of the ISA server.

In short, the problem is the ISA server. Although it is still a mystery on why the machine would contact the ISA server if the IIS server hosting the site is located on the machine itself (localhost).

Workaround: Use the bypassonlocal property.

```xml
<configuration>
   <system.net>
      <defaultProxy>
         <proxy proxyaddress="<ISA-SERVER>" bypassonlocal="true"/>
      </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) file:

```
127.0.0.1 machine.computer.local
```

Comment: We already tried this. Problem is, when we tried to ping "machine.computer.local" locally, the IP being returned is not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I think that you will have more chance getting a correct answer in serverfault.com. Voting to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Under "configuration" section in Web.config add this:

```
 <system.net>
   <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"></defaultProxy>
 </system.net>
```

Then works like a charm!